# How to pass variable from MainWindow to SecondWindow in Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt

I have a pushbutton on my main form named `pushButton_Tar1ex`, it has some text on it. I have another pushbutton on my main form named `pushButton_RenameTargets`.

When I push `pushButton_RenameTargets`, the following code executes:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_RenameTargets_clicked()
{
    RenameTargets renametargets;
    renametargets.target1NameCurrent = ui->pushButton_Tar1ex->text();
    renametargets.setModal(true);
    renametargets.exec();
}
```

So my second window is called `RenameTargets` and the first line of code in the function creates an object `renametargets`. Then I set `renametargets.target1NameCurrent = ui->pushButton_Tar1ex->text();`which `target1NameCurrent` is in the public: portion of renametargets.h. Then in RenameTargets I set the label to the pushbuttontext by:

```
RenameTargets::RenameTargets(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::RenameTargets)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->label_currentNameTarget1->setText(target1NameCurrent);

}
```

Yet nothing appears in the label `label_currentNameTarget1`.

I have run some qDebug stuff and what happens is when `RenameTargets renametargets;` is run when I push the button it runs through the `RenameTargets ui(new Ui::RenameTargets)` part before the `renametargets.target1NameCurrent = ui->pushButton_Tar1ex->text();` is declared.

What am I doing wrong? any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you set `renametargets.target1NameCurrent` member variable after constructing your object `renametargets`... that's the problem, since you use `target1NameCurrent` in your constructor to set your label.

One solution is to pass `target1NameCurrent` through the constructor.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_RenameTargets_clicked()
{
  RenameTargets renametargets(this, ui->pushButton_Tar1ex->text());
  renametargets.setModal(true);
  renametargets.exec();
}
```

RenameTargets.cpp

```
RenameTargets::RenameTargets(QWidget *parent, const QString & target1NameCurrent):
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::RenameTargets),
    target1NameCurrent(target1NameCurrent)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);
  ui->label_currentNameTarget1->setText(target1NameCurrent);

}
```

RenameTargets.h

```
class RenameTargets{
  public:
    RenameTargets(QWidget *parent, const QString & target1NameCurrent);

};
```

Also, you can just initialize `label_currentNameTarget1` in another function in `RenameTargets` after constructing `renametargets` and initializing `renametargets.target1NameCurrent`.

Comment: how? sorry im a newbie :)

Comment: @Scientized I added an example

Comment: I get an error error: no matching function for call to 'RenameTargets::RenameTargets(QString)'
     RenameTargets renametargets(ui->pushButton_Tar1ex->text());
                                                              ^

Comment: @Scientized did u change the constructor declaration in the header file to match the definition in my code ?

Comment: @Scientized I did. btw, how do you debug this code without knowing what a header file is !

Comment: Copied your code exactly, still doesnt work. Get the same error. I do know what a header file is, but have been on this problem for hours so I just wanted to be explicit in everything because it is driving me crazy.

Comment: @Scientized ... ok, if you have the 1st argument as `parent`, just pass `this`  .. try the updated code ... sounds like initially you have `parent` optional.

Comment: @Scientized  you welcome :) ! happy that I helped !!